# Dividing 2 integer columns in pandas DataFrame in Python 3 returns rounded integer instead of float

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, division

I have the following pandas DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1, 2, 3],
                   "A": [54, 53, 50],
                   "B": [52, 49, 46]})
```

Now I want a new column `C` that is the result of dividing the values in column `B` by the values of column `A`. However, when I run:

```
df["C"] =  df["B"] / df["A"]
```

the result is:

```
    id  A   B   C
0   1   54  52  1
1   2   53  49  1
2   3   50  46  1
```

The column C seems to be automatically rounded up to an integer, which should not happen. I read some other Stack Overflow posts, which say that in Python 3 (which I'm using) the conversion to float should automatically happen. From another post I tried this:

```
df["C"] =  df["B"] * 1.00 / df["A"]
```

But that still gave the same wrong result. How to solve this?

Comment: with the example in question, I cannot replicate the problem, this returns the expected `[0.9629629629629629, 0.9245283018867925, 0.92]` for me, have you by chance used any display settings? like `pd.options.display.float_format`?

Comment: Yes I first had set pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.0f}'.format, but I commented that line out and re-run the code. Could this be the problem?

Comment: Thats the issue right there. set `pd.options.display.float_format = None` and rerun

Comment: You are amazing, it works! Should you want to earn rep, I would accept your answer if you wrote it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try. -

```
df["C"] = df.A.astype(float) / df.B.astype(float)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I set

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.0f}'.format
```

But commented it out and thought this would solve it. Instead, changing it to:

```
pd.options.display.float_format = None
```

solved the problem